How to migrate from Poetry to UV package manager?
I'm planning to switch from poetry to the uv Python package manager, but I can't find any migration guides. Currently, I'm using poetry and already have a pyproject.toml file.
What key(s) should be modified or added to migrate properly to uv?
Here’s the current pyproject.toml structure:
[tool.poetry]
name = "name"
version = "1.6.0"
description = ""
authors = [
    "...",
]
maintainers = [
    "...",
]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
fastapi = "^0.115.2"
uvicorn = { version = "^0.32.0", extras = ["standard"] }
pydantic = "^2.5.3"
pydantic-settings = "^2"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^8.3.3"
flake8 = "~7.1.1"
mypy = "^1.12"

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
multi_line_output = 3

[tool.mypy]
strict = true
ignore_missing_imports = true


[tool.pytest.ini_options]
filterwarnings = [
    "error",
    "ignore::DeprecationWarning",
    "ignore:.*unclosed.*:ResourceWarning",
]
env = [
    "...=...",
    "...=...",
]

[tool.coverage.run]
omit = [
    "...=...",
    "...=...",
]

[tool.coverage.report]
exclude_lines = [
    "pragma: no cover",
    "if TYPE_CHECKING",
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Additionally, in the [build-system] section, I currently have poetry-core. Should this be replaced with something specific for uv during the migration?

I would just delete it (and the poetry.lock) and start again from scratch, adding dependencies with uv.  It will take much longer to manually edit this file.

First, you need to convert your poetry compatible pyproject.toml to be compatible with uv. You can actually do it quite easily with pdm (originally suggested here).

uvx pdm import pyproject.toml
Remove all poetry sections in the pyproject (i.e. [tool.poetry...] sections)
Replace

[tool.pdm.dev-dependencies]

with
[dependency-groups]

Done. Your pyproject.toml file is now compatible with UV and you can do uv lock or uv sync.
Having said that, it is likely that UV will resolve completely different versions of packages than what you already had in your poetry.lock. That doesn't have to be a problem, but can. It was a problem in my case.
To work around this, I used a small script to hardcode all the minor/patch versions of my packages in pyproject.toml before converting to uv compatible format. Then, after conversion, I would create the uv.lock with uv lock. Then, I'd undo the hardcoded versions in the original pyproject.toml and convert again. Because uv by default will prefer versions from the lock, you now have all your versions pinned as they were in poetry and mostly the same packages in the lock (dependencies of dependencies can be different). It should be safe to do uv sync without worrying about things breaking due to versions change.
Below is the script I used to hardcode minor/patch versions in pyproject.toml. It's not perfect and will create incorrect results for dependencies with extras/from git etc. but these are easy to tweak manually.
from pathlib import Path

import toml

# Load poetry.lock and pyproject.toml
lockfile_path = Path("poetry.lock")
pyproject_path = Path("pyproject.toml")

# Parse the lock file
with lockfile_path.open("r") as lockfile:
    lock_data = toml.load(lockfile)

# Parse pyproject.toml
with pyproject_path.open("r") as pyproject_file:
    pyproject_data = toml.load(pyproject_file)

# Build a map of package names to their specific versions from poetry.lock
locked_versions = {package["name"]: package["version"] for package in lock_data["package"]}


# Helper function to update dependencies in a given section
def update_dependencies(dependencies):
    for dep_name, dep_constraint in dependencies.items():
        if dep_name in locked_versions:
            dependencies[dep_name] = locked_versions[dep_name]
            print(f"Updated {dep_name} to version {locked_versions[dep_name]}")
        else:
            print(f"{dep_name} not found in poetry.lock, skipping.")


# Update dependencies in pyproject.toml
update_dependencies(pyproject_data["tool"]["poetry"]["dependencies"])
update_dependencies(pyproject_data["tool"]["poetry"]["group"]["dev"]["dependencies"])

# Write the updated pyproject.toml
with pyproject_path.open("w") as pyproject_file:
    toml.dump(pyproject_data, pyproject_file)

print("pyproject.toml has been updated with specific versions.")


What the heck is pdm?

Now for step 3, just need replace [tool.pdm.dev-dependencies] to [dependency-groups] based on the doc.  Because uv uses the [dependency-groups] table (as defined in PEP 735) for declaration of development dependencies.

Hi @fccoelho, I think Bartosz just borrows pdm as a temporary tool to help convert which is quite smart. However, in uv case, there is no need pdm, which is why step replaces it.

The link to the original pdm workflow leads me to x.com, but I don't see the actual steps there (at least not without logging in).

@squarespiral this answer is self contained. The link to x is just to give credit to the person who originally suggested using PDM.

I also had to remove the following sections from the pyproject.toml, that is generated by pdm: [tool.pdm.build], [build-system]. Also this workflow will add the python requirement to pyproject.toml. While this is permitted in uv, the standard behaviour is to have the python requirement in a different file "python.version" with simply the version number as file content e.g. "3.12".

Addition to previous comment: uv standard behaviour is to have the python version in pyproject.toml and in python.version. So if you follow the workflow above, just add the python.version file.

I had success using https://lib.rs/crates/uv-migrator.
After installation I converted my poetry project (which used a private package repository) using
$ uv-migrator . --import-index https://<user>:<password>@custom.pypi.org/simple/

It worked except for two issues which the uv-migrator did not handle correctly:

Add a build system at the end of the newly generated pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"


Add a section [[tool.uv.index]] (note the double brackets) to configure my private package repository
[[tool.uv.index]]
name = "custom"
url = "custom.pypi.org/simple/"



Everything else (including dependency groups, configuration of ruff linter) was converted correctly.

Another very recently released tool is migrate-to-uv. Run:
uvx migrate-to-uv

to migrate from Poetry or pipenv to uv. This will rewrite your pyproject.toml file and remove poetry.lock. You still need to uv lock afterwards.
