How to migrate from a simple Python project : requirements.txt setup.py (setuptools), to a uv project
If I want to use uv in an already existing project named my_project with only a requirements.txt (or requirements.in),  and simple setup.py(setuptools), that has been installed with pip install -e ..
How would I switch from setuptools to uv?
If my project has this file configuration:
my_project
├── my_project
│   └── hello.py
├── tests
│   └── test_hello.py
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py

The uv documentation offer two type of projects organisation, the app (uv init --app example-app) that correspond to the one I have, and the library one uv init --lib example-lib, which is based on a src layout organisation.
uv allows to publish a library directly on Pypi, do I need to change my layout for a src one if I want to deploy library with uv?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79118841/how-to-migrate-from-poetry-to-uv-package-manager

@mkrieger1 Probably the src layout.

This might not be the best solution, but here is what I did. I will accept any better solution as an answer!
Initialize uv
Being at the root of my_project with the command line, run:
$ uv init


delete the hello.py file that has been created at the root.
Modify the info of the pyproject.toml, you probably should include the info present in your setup.py (description, authors and so on).
delete your setup.py file.

Add dependencies
$ uv add -r requirements.in (or requirements.txt)

Install library
$ uv pip install -e . 

Modify the Makefile:
Makefile:
install_library:
    uv sync # pip install -r 
    uv pip install -e . # replace pip install -e . requirements.in
run_a_script:
    uv run python ./my_lib/my_script.py # replace python ./my_lib/my_script.py
launch_test:
    uv run pytest -n auto --cov-report=xml # replace uv run pytest -n auto --cov-report=xml

Modify a potential CI (example for github action)
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with: 
        lfs: true 
    - name: Install uv
      uses: astral-sh/setup-uv@v3

    - name: "Set up Python"
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
    - name: Set up Python environment
      run: |
        make install_library
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        make launch_test

Deploy on Pypi
Deployment does not need to use the --lib/src layout, the app layout allows to deploy a library without issues.
$ uv build
$ uv publish

then you shoud give token as username, and the token from Pypi to publish and make your library installable with pip install my_project.
